# Unable to install tensorflow on windows using anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have tried installing tensorflow on my windows by using anaconda but I keep getting error messages. Then I read some more resources on installation and the error were gone but now I get this error when I try to import it. Please help me fix it
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/DeLL/Desktop/py/Codewars Apr2020-/3kyu.py', wdir='C:/Users/DeLL/Desktop/py/Codewars Apr2020-')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/DeLL/Desktop/py/Codewars Apr2020-/3kyu.py", line 431, in 
    import tensorflow as tf

File "C:\Users\DeLL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 41, in 
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

File "C:\Users\DeLL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 50, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

File "C:\Users\DeLL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DeLL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\DeLL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\DeLL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

To install tensorflow in conda environment, run the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

if the problem persists try https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow